# Variable is undefined in Sass @each statement that implements the @use module

Tags: css, sass

I have started a new website project using Dart Sass and the **@use** and **@forward** modules.

When I compile the Sass using `sass --watch static/scss/style.scss:static/css/style.css` using on my Mac using Terminal, the following error is output:

```
Error: Undefined variable.
@each $name, $weight in $font-weights {
static/scss/base/_base.scss 2:27  @forward
static/scss/base/_index.scss 3:1  @use
static/scss/style.scss 2:1        root stylesheet
```

The $font-weights map looks like this:

```
$font-weights: (
  "thin": 300,
  "regular": 400,
  "heavy": 700,
);
```

The following code is included in the **_base.scss** file in the base directory, which is included in the same directory as the **_typography.scss** file that contains the **$font-weights** map.

```
html {
  @each $name, $weight in $font-weights {
    --font-weight-#{$name}: #{$weight};
  }
}
```

The **_index.scss** file in the base directory contains the following:

```
@forward "reset";
@forward "typography";
@forward "base";
```

And the main style.scss file in the root scss directory contains the following:

```
@use "abstracts";
@use "base";
@use "components";
@use "layouts";
```

I have tried the **@use** with and without name spaces using the `@use "base" as *` and `@use "base" as base`, but both have not helped fix the issue.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is not working for me.

Cheers,

[image: Sass directory structure]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue with some extra work and a bit of additional reading up on how to use **@use**. I have detailed my resolution below.

First, I removed the `@use "abstracts"` line from the main **style.scss** file, then I added `@use "../abstracts" as a` to the top of the **_base.scss** file.

In my setup, the **_base.scss** file is being used to collect all of the elements starting from the html root and going on from there.

After that, I updated the main **style.scss** file to use the following namespaced **@use** imports.

```
@use "base" as b;
@use "components" as c;
@use "layouts" as l;
```

Hopefully this helps anyone that runs into similar issues while learning the new **@use** and **@forward** import system.